# Pop_OS! 21.04 - DNS not working

Tags: dns, networkmanager, pop-os, resolv.conf

Edit: this problem may be related to the fact that my `resolv.conf` file is no longer a symlink due to my previous use of ProtonVPN...

Edit 2: just tried re-linking it to `/run/resolvconf/resolv.conf` and my internet works perfectly now. This appears to be a problem with the VPN replacing `resolv.conf` and not reverting it when it disconnects. This answer helped me identify and solve the problem: [DNS settings not working on lubuntu 17.10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423148/492904)

I am running the latest version of Pop_OS 21.04 on my laptop. It was working fine until yesterday, when I suddenly disconnected from a Discord call and was no longer able to access the internet. I have investigated the problem and have determined it to be DNS-related, as I can still access internet sites (like 1.1.1.1) if I manually input the IP address for the destination, but I cannot access non-IP domains. (like google.com)

I believe the problem has something to do with my `/etc/resolv.conf` file, which can be edited to contain the line `nameserver 1.1.1.1` to successfully get my DNS working again. However, this file is rewritten to the following upon reboot or restarting the `NetworkManager` service:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver ::1
```

I understand that this has something to do with an internal DNS server, but I don't know what would be managing this DNS server or where I would go to change the config.

The file `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` contains the line `dns=default` and changing this to say `dns=dnsmasq` affects the generated `resolv.conf` file to contain the line `nameserver 127.0.0.53` instead of the above `::1`.

To solve this, I would like to be able to set a persistent global DNS configuration for my system that ignores all other DNS settings, though I am unsure of how to do that. Editing the `head` file for `resolvconf` didn't seem to affect `resolv.conf`, perhaps because `resolv.conf` is being generated only by `NetworkManager`.

Perhaps there is a place to edit the default config of the generated `resolv.conf` somewhere in `/etc/NetworkManager`, but I have been unable to find anything thus far. I would like to avoid making `resolv.conf` a persistent file, as I fear it may break something, but at this point I'm considering it. Preferably I would change how it is generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out it was a problem with my VPN messing with the symlink at `resolv.conf` and not properly fixing it after disconnecting.

From this answer to [DNS settings not working on lubuntu 17.10](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423148/492904):

> Your DNS configuration is failing because when protonVPN is being
> activated, it is deleting your original `/etc/resolv.conf` symlink,
> and replacing it with a file of their own.
>
> When it goes down, unfortunately, it does not recreate the symbolic
> link, and thus effectively creates a disconnect between the
> `/etc/resolv.conf` file and resolvconf/`NetworkManager`.
>
> To correct this question, you have to run the following commands
> *every single time after using (disconnecting) the VPN* to restore the resolvconf symlink:
>
> ```
> sudo rm /etc/resolv.conf
> sudo ln -s /run/resolvconf/resolv.conf /etc/resolv.conf
> ```
>
> I would also open a ticket with protonVPN, as this is a relatively
> known issue and a common occurrence with the software of some VPN
> providers.
>
> *Another possible (temporary) workaround for someone more familiar with Linux, is not being dependent on NetWorkManager and resolvconf,
> and dealing directly with the manual configuration of the interfaces.*

Answer (score 0):

It once solved my issue but today it happened again. And it wasn't the solution. I fixed it with editing /etc/resolv.conf  and adding line nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
.

Previously I also tried:
adding

```
sudo nano /etc/systemd/network/99-custom-dns.conf
```

inside this file

```
[Network]
DNS=8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
```

than restarting

```
sudo systemctl restart systemd-networkd systemd-resolved
```

and restarting all the networking

```
sudo nmcli networking off
sudo nmcli networking on
```

In the end I fixed making my /etc/resolve
by changing line to nameserver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4